# Tab Video in IOS browser

Tags: android, ios, api, video, youtube

I develop a web site which enable to people to look videos from youtube, dailymotion or vimeo (for now).

I use an iframe too display videos on mobile device (ios/android). I don't have any problems.

**Question** :
When i go to youtube.com from my iphone and i read a video, when the video is finished, the "video tab" close automatically. It is the same thing in dailymotion.com, but not in vimeo.com.

Do people know how to make this in my website ? Maybe a param i don't know, some javascript code ?

Thank you !!